# How to get custom url in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have created rails project with scaffold
http://localhost:3000/games/

when i adds new game i gets url as 
http://localhost:3000/games/first-game

i want to change this to
http://localhost:3000/game/first-game 
or
http://localhost:3000/first-game

my route file have

```
resources :games
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the resources `games` to act as a root path, you can set it's path to '/' in **routes.rb**

```
resources :games, path: '/'
```

If you only want it for the `show` action (as I suppose you do), use:

```
resources :games, path: '/', only: [:show]
resources :games, except: [:show]
```

(This will give http://localhost:3000/first-game)

Or third, which is probably wisest to avoid conflicting routes, call the `show` action using the singular 'game' path:

```
resources :games, path: 'game', only: [:show]
resources :games, except: [:show]
```

(This will give http://localhost:3000/game/first-game)

Comment: Hi mgrim thanks, last option works but not for destroy action.

Comment: It doesn't? Interesting. (I assume you have ```[:show, :destroy]``` in both lines.) What does ```$ rake routes``` output?

Comment: After adding :destroy it works but edit stops. $ rake route output :- Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
edit_game GET    /game/:id/edit(.:format) games#edit
     game GET    /game/:id(.:format)      games#show
          DELETE /game/:id(.:format)      games#destroy
    games GET    /games(.:format)         games#index
          POST   /games(.:format)         games#create
 new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)     games#new
          PATCH  /games/:id(.:format)     games#update
          PUT    /games/:id(.:format)     games#update

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom route for your action like this:

```
get '/games/first-game' => 'Games#first_game'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as :

```
resources :games
  member do
    get 'first-game', to: 'games#first_game', as: :first_game
  end
end
```

Read [Naming Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) guide.